# Multi NSDictionary returns string instead of child

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to access keys from a multi NSDictionary.

This is my output from NSLog

```
Berlijn[23667:60b] data = {
    1 =     {
        data =         (
            4,
            0,
            0,
            0
        );
        key = "June 2014";
    };
}
```

When I try to loop through this dictionary and log the key I get NSInvalidArgumentException because `key` is a NSString.

This is my current code:

```
- (void) updateRating: (int) companyID {
    APICaller *api = [[APICaller alloc] init];

    [api setUrl:@"http://domain.examle/api/getcompanyhistory.php"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"token": [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken],
                                 @"device_token" : [defaults stringForKey:@"uniqueToken"],
                                 @"companyid" : @(companyID)
                                 };



    [api setParameters: parameters];
    [api sendPostRequest: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"data = %@", responseObject);


        for(NSDictionary *contentData in responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"contentData = %@", [contentData objectForKey:@"key"]);
        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

As NSDictionary is a dictionary I don't know why it returns a string.

Update (error message):

```
2014-06-02 01:41:41.386 Berlijn[23747:60b] -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1784253e0
2014-06-02 01:41:41.387 Berlijn[23747:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1784253e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1860a309c 0x192021d78 0x1860a7d14 0x1860a5a7c 0x185fc54ac 0x1000eb8ac 0x1000ea014 0x1925f0420 0x1925f03e0 0x1925f356c 0x186062d64 0x1860610a4 0x185fa1b38 0x18b9c7830 0x188fe00e8 0x1000eaff4 0x19260baa0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message.

Comment: That error message isn't saying that "key" is a string, it's saying that you're sending objectForKey to a string -- the only object you're sending it to in the code you posted is "contentData". You should log the class of contentData and see what it says. You should also add an exception breakpoint to show what line is causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you call `contentData` a dictionary does NOT make it one.

Fast enumeration of a dictionary iterates over keys, NOT values. Your key is a string (even though you call it an `NSDictionary`) and will throw an exception when you try to call `objectForKey:` on it.

Since `responseObject` is a dictionary you can iterate over the keys AND values using `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop))`.

Another option is to use fast enumeration correctly like so...

```
for(NSString *key in responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"contentData = %@", [responseObject objectForKey:key]);
}
```